# Change source and destination address iptables

Tags: iptables

I need to transform destination IP of packets when they arrive from our client, ands also transform the source IP of packages leaving our network to the client's network.

I have IPSec VPN tunnel with a client on a Linux box. The machine has two interfaces with the following config:

```
eth0: 172.15.100.5
eth1: 172.15.100.15 (public IP 33.x.x.x)
```

Application server is `172.15.100.50`.

Clients IP: `10.26.18.38/32`

Client cannot use our internal IP `172.15.100.50` to talk to the application via the tunnel. Instead, they will send traffic through the VPN to `172.20.100.55` (which is not our IP) and they need us to response with source IP as  `172.20.100.55`.

My thinking is that I should be able to use iptables `POSTROUTING` and `PREROUTING` transform destination IP of incoming traffic from `10.20.100.55` to `172.15.100.50` (application server), and outgoing traffic from our network application server IP `172.15.100.50` to `10.20.100.55`. However, I am not sure of the correct way to achieve this.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth1 -d 10.20.100.55 -j DNAT --to 172.15.100.50
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -i eth0 -d 10.26.18.38 -j SNAT --to 172.20.100.55
```

I have monitored traffic with tcpdump and on the application server, but it would appear my NAT rule is not working.

Comment: Maybe you should also try to ask the question on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com)